# Iterating over values and variable names in dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the following script to make a table in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

get_probability <- function(parameter_array, threshold) {
  return(round(100 * sum(parameter_array >= threshold) /
                 length(parameter_array)))
}

thresholds = c(75, 100, 125)

mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    low=get_probability(disp, thresholds[[1]]),
    medium=get_probability(disp, thresholds[[2]]),
    high=get_probability(disp, thresholds[[3]]),
    )
```

The table that comes out is the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   gear   low medium  high
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3   100    100    93
2     4    92     67    50
3     5   100     80    60
```

My question is, how can condense what I have passed to `summarise` to a single line? i.e., is there a way to iterate over both the `thresholds` vector, also while passing custom variable names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent versions of `dplyr`, `summarise` will auto-splice data.frames created within it into new columns. So, you just need a way to iterate over thresholds to create a data.frame.
One option is `purrr:::map_dfc`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

get_probability <- function(parameter_array, threshold) {
  return(round(100 * sum(parameter_array >= threshold) /
                 length(parameter_array)))
}

thresholds = c(75, 100, 125)

thresholds <- setNames(thresholds, c('low', 'medium', 'high'))

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(purrr::map_dfc(thresholds, ~ get_probability(disp, .x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    gear   low medium  high
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3   100    100    93
#> 2     4    92     67    50
#> 3     5   100     80    60
```

If you prefer not to use an extra package though, you could just `lapply` and then convert the output to data.frame. (Replace `\(x)` with `function(x)` in older versions of R)

```r
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(as.data.frame(lapply(thresholds, \(x) get_probability(disp, x))))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    gear   low medium  high
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3   100    100    93
#> 2     4    92     67    50
#> 3     5   100     80    60
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>